# Builds fail with missing file (that isn't missing)

Tags: travis-ci

My builds on a branch are failing, while they work OK on master. The build depends on a dotfile (present in both branches) and the failures all say that the file cannot be found. Travis seems to be doing something to mess with my files on branches?

Example build that fails: https://travis-ci.org/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/builds/72428562

Example from same repo (same change even) that succeeds: https://travis-ci.org/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/builds/72428617

Comment: I never got anything back from the Travis team (do they ever respond to support requests if you don't pay them money?). The problem was in my build though because the files in question were actually being removed by mistake during the build process.